# Disable submit button if no change is done to the form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I have a form which uses `react-bootstrap` components and when the form loads,the fields will be populated with default values and these fields can be edited. I want to keep my submit button disabled if no change is done for the form. If any change is done for the form, i want the submit button to be able to submit.

In angularjs you can do this using `pristine` , `dirty` etc. How can i do it in reactjs and react bootstrap?

**My form**

```
<Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <div id="" className="pb-3 pr-lg-5 pr-xs-0">
      <div id="form_data" className="pb-3 pr-0">

         <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formAddress">
            <Form.Label column sm="2" lg="4">
               <label className="label_type2">Address</label>
            </Form.Label>
            <Col sm="10" lg="8">
            <Form.Control type="text" defaultValue={login.userInfoLoading === true ? 'Loading...' : userInfoAddress.address} className="input_text" required />
            </Col>
         </Form.Group>

         <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPostalCode">
            <Form.Label column sm="2" lg="4">
               <label className="label_type2">Postal code</label>
            </Form.Label>
            <Col sm="10" lg="4">
            <Form.Control type="text" defaultValue={login.userInfoLoading === true ? 'Loading...' : userInfoAddress.cep} className="input_text" required />
            </Col>
         </Form.Group>
      </div>

      <Button type="submit" size="lg" variant="light" className="mt-5 mb-3 btn_type1" id="button_primary_clr">Update information</Button>
   </div>
</Form>
```

Comment: Since you are not using redux form you need to handle it by writing a custom function, because redux form has this property called isDirty !!

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS No. I'm using react-bootstrap for my input components

Comment: I have added the logic how to achieve this, Kindly check and let me know !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using redux form, i will explain the logic how you need to achieve it

So your state will have a key and value like the below format, these are the pre populated values

```
state = {formValues:{firstName: 'John', secondName: 'Doe', Address: ''}, isFormDirty: false}
```

So based on the initial state of **isFormDirty** you can disable the button, since there is no changes

Now you need to attach a method to **Form** at the top level, since event delegation happens you will get the event from the child input so assume **firstName** field user has changed now you can have a object as inside state when the component loads

```
changedValues: {firstName: false, secondName: false, Address: false}
```

Now you have two objects changedValues and formValues

```
onFormHandleChange = (e) => {
 // compare the current value and pre populated value
  e.target.value === formValues[e.target.name]
// if its true
 changedValues[e.target.name] = true
 else false
}
```

so based on this changedValues object like 
 `Object.values(this.state.changedValues)` array contains true you can make **isFormDirty** to true

since state updated your button gets enabled

I hope this will give a better understanding of the problem